# ERDAS Imagine batch wizard edit replacement pattern help

Tags: erdas-imagine, batch

I'm using ERDAS Imagine to batch produce NDVIs from NAIP imagery.  I need to also replace the default file name (e.g. "m_3610132_nw_14_1_20100503") with a user friendly file name (e.g. 3610132nw).  How can I change the edit replacement pattern in the batch wizard to output a subset of the original filename?

Example:
z:/project/studyarea_8_naip/ok_naip/temp_out/$(Input.pathright)$(Input.root)

yields => m_3610132_nw_14_1_20100503

However, I want the output to be simply 3610132nw

Comment: To merge multiple user profiles, Aaron, please visit http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts.  (Moderators can no longer do this for you.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how to do this in ERDAS but I've previously used a program called ReNamer ([download link](http://www.snapfiles.com/get/denrenamer.html) for such batch renaming tasks. Perhaps this might be useful.